# python does not find module installed with pipx

Tags: python, debian, pipx

Debain stable wants me to install Python modules using pipx. So I do

```
$ pipx install auditwheel
$ pipx ensurepath
$ python3 -m pipx ensurepath
$ python3
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import auditwheel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'auditwheel'
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats the feature of pipx - if you install auditwheel and ensurepath with pipx - both of those are installed into separate "virtual environments" and they are available only if the venv of those is activated. Which happens when their respected cli entrypoints are executed. TL;DR pipx is intended to be used to install standalone applications that are completely isolated from any other python env.

Comment: aka, use `pip` instead of `pipx` and check out how to utilize virtual environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Python 3.11 onward, Debian encourages the users to create a separate Python virtual environment to install Python packages.

Because Debian declares its Python install to be *externally-managed*, `pip` (and other installers) will refuse to install packages system-wide. Installation is only possible in virtual environments or separate Python installs.
This is because Python package installers (like `pip`) are unaware of the constraints that APT-managed packages have on libraries and versions. See [PEP-668](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668) for a full discussion of the problems that can occur when multiple installers operate on the same Python install.

Therefore, the optimal way is to create a virtual environment, say `MyEnv`, and install packages therein:

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/.venvs  # create a folder for all virtual environments 
$ python3 -m venv $HOME/.venvs/MyEnv  # create MyEnv
```

This will create a directory `$HOME/.venvs/MyEnv` with a configuration file `pyvenv.cfg` which includes some details for this virtual environment, such as the Python executable and Python version.

Verify the version of the Python in the virtual environment:

```
$HOME/.venvs/MyEnv/bin/python --version
```

The executables of the created virtual environment are found under `$HOME/.venvs/MyEnv/bin`.

To install a package into the virtual environment, use

```
$HOME/.venvs/MyEnv/bin/python -m pip install <some-package>
```

To 'activate' the virtual enviroment, i.e. adding its configuration variables into the shell environment, use

```
source $HOME/.venvs/MyEnv/bin/activate
```

Consult Python's guide to `virtualenv` and `pip` at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments.

Comment: how does this refers to the actual question ?  Of course, pipx uses virtual environments but it does not address "what did i do wrong" ..

Comment: but kudos for preaching about venv's

Answer (score 0):

Debian docs at https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#python3-pep-668

> If you need to install a Python **application** (or version) that isn't packaged in Debian, we recommend that you install it with pipx (in the pipx Debian package). pipx will set up an environment isolated from other applications and system Python modules, and install the application and its dependencies into that.

Emphasis mine, the docs do talk about **application** and under that paragraph is second one pointing to installing packages to the virtual environment;

> If you need to install a Python library module (or version) that isn't packaged in Debian, we recommend installing it into a virtualenv, where possible. You can create virtualenvs with the venv Python stdlib module (in the python3-venv Debian package) or the virtualenv Python 3rd-party tool (in the virtualenv Debian package). For example, instead of running pip install --user foo, run: mkdir -p ~/.venvs && python3 -m venv ~/.venvs/foo && ~/.venvs/foo/bin/python -m pip install foo to install it in a dedicated virtualenv.

For which @AlQuemist's answer also highlights ..

Comment: I believe using Python's _universal_ `venv` explicitly is far better than arbitrary tools like `pipx`, esp. for developers living on different platforms.

Comment: Not disagreeing with that ;) its all just PATH shuffling

Answer (score -1):

`pipx` is not exactly the same as `pip`. `pipx` installs applications in an isolated environment. It will not help if you want to compile and import a module. You can use a virtual environment as @AlQuemist suggests.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35225337)

Comment: @vencaslac It does provide an answer to the question. It's just expanding on another answer.